# Spark StorageLevel in local mode not working?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

- Running in Local mode
- Computer's Memory: **16GB**
- Computer's Available Disk Space: **500GB**
- Input File Size: **50GB**
- Error Message: **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space**
- Code: **typed into windows command prompt after using .\pyspark in command window**

**Code**

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
import pyspark

rdd = sc.textFile('file:///myBigFile.xml')
rdd.persist(pyspark.StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY)

rdd.take(60).show() ****Blows up here****
```

Reading the documentation on `StorageLevel`

> Flags for controlling the storage of an RDD. Each StorageLevel records
>   whether to use memory, whether to drop the RDD to disk if it falls out
>   of memory

If this is really true, then why does this code blow a gasket?

Others have encountered something similar and appears to be an open defect.

As referenced below:
SPARK-24961 - sort operation causes out of memory
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24961

Comment: You should assign the result back. `rdd = rdd.persist(...)`

Comment: If you check the source code, `persist()` just returns the same RDD reference that is passed in, so it doesn't make any different whether you assign the result back.

Comment: @DNA - I realized that after a while.  Probably because it's not a transformation.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is a common problem, in my experience; even if you specify DISK_ONLY or MEMORY_AND_DISK, persistence appears to consume some memory and can easily cause OutOfMemoryErrors.

Note that `persist()` is only worth using if you are repeatedly using the same RDD and need to avoid regenerating it from the original dataset. If you are using it only once or twice, it is often faster to leave it unpersisted, and is much less likely to fail due to memory errors.

You may also want to try turning up the amount of memory allocated to your executors; this might be enough to avoid the error.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is probably a wrong usage of persist operation. Persist is used to store whole rdd-content to given location, default is in memory. Your rdd is a 50gb file and this will not fit into memory. StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY will copy your file into temp-location of spark. In this way your file exists in two copies on disk without added value.

```
1: rdd = sc.textFile('file:///myBigFile.xml')
2: small_rdd = heavy_computation(rdd).persist()
3: rdd1 = more_heavy_computation(small_rdd)
4: rdd2 = more_heavy_computation(small_rdd)
```

In this example intermediate result (2:) is stored by persist() into memory. I assume intermediate result was very expensive to calculate (heavy on cpu usage for large amount of time) and fits to memory. You need the result twice (3:/4:). Without using persist line 3 and 4 would recompute heavy_computation. Using persist()  heavy_computation is done once and intermediate result is used for 3+4.

NOTE: If calculation of intermediate result was very expensive but fits not to memory, DISK_ONLY is an alternative. For example intermediate result took a whole day to compute, it would be better to save it to disk instead of computing it for second time.

Note, spark works lazy. Above example will do noting, cpu will start working when adding this:

```
6: rdd1.show()
7: rdd2.show()
```

Operations like show/save/write/... lets spark begin computation.

```
rdd = sc.textFile('file:///myBigFile.xml')
rdd.take(60).show()
```

This will run fast and should not run out of memory.

Comment: "This will run fast and should not run out of memory."  Unfortunately that's exactly what it doesn't do.  If I do only those two lines of code it blows up right away.